# Get selected button id in array using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get id's of selected buttons in an array from `button-checkbox`. I am able to successfully show the selected button's id in view but unable to get the selected ids in array form in controller.

Here is my HTML code

```
    <html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS BootStrap UI radios</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="btn-group-justified">
    <label ng-repeat="service in availability.services" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-model="service.selected" ng-click="test(availability.services)" btn-checkbox >{{service.name}}</label>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="service in availability.services"><span ng-show="service.selected">{{service.id}}</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is controller

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var services = [ 
    { name:'Service A',id:1 },
    { name:'Service B',id:2},
    { name:'Service C',id:3 },
    { name:'Service D',id:4}
  ];

  $scope.availability = { services:services };
});
```

please see the plnker link

http://plnkr.co/edit/DeVPNug9APWWpwZByvnu?p=preview

Comment: **unable to show id in array** What do you mean???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$scope.getSelectedIDs = function() {
    var ids = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.availability.services, function(service) {
        if (service.selected) {
            ids.push(service.id);
        }
    })

    return ids;
};
```

Now, just call the method `$scope.getSelectedIDs()` anywhere in your controller where you want the selected ids in array.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rS47sIEo1HaaDqrc3BUw?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var services = [{
    name: 'Service A',
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Service B',
    id: 2
  }, {
    name: 'Service C',
    id: 3
  }, {
    name: 'Service D',
    id: 4
  }];

  $scope.availability = {
    services: services
  };

  $scope.getSelectedIDs = function() {
    var ids = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.availability.services, function(service) {
      if (service.selected) {
        ids.push(service.id);
      }
    })

    return ids;
  };

  $scope.alertMeSelectedIDs = function() {
    console.log($scope.getSelectedIDs());
    alert($scope.getSelectedIDs());
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS BootStrap UI radios</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="btn-group-justified">
    <label ng-repeat="service in availability.services" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="service.selected" ng-click="test(availability.services)" btn-checkbox>{{service.name}}</label>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="service in availability.services"><span ng-show="service.selected">{{service.id}}</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <a ng-click="alertMeSelectedIDs()">Show me selected</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's perfect but I just want to show array in console not in view part hope you got it

Comment: Yes Sure. I've updated the answer. Open the browser console, hit the above **Run code snippet** button, select some service and hit **Show me selected**. You will see the values in console.

Comment: Hi @shashank Thanks for your code but please tell me that how I can retrieve that array after click on button I want that dynamic generated array (button are those 4 not  through any external link)

Comment: I've already added that in the answer yesterday. See `alertMeSelectedIDs()` method and the `<a>` tag in HTML.

Comment: but I want to show after click on button not through any external link

Comment: Oh man!! Just put that into a button `<button type="button" ng-click="alertMeSelectedIDs()">Show me selected</button>` Please read about `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0):

I have forked the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/eQxsq194qqRUo8Vs326H?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var services = [ 
    { name:'Service A',id:1 },
    { name:'Service B',id:2},
    { name:'Service C',id:3 },
    { name:'Service D',id:4}
  ];

  $scope.availability = { services:services };


  $scope.test = function (service){
    console.log (service);
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="btn-group-justified">
    <label ng-repeat="service in availability.services" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-model="service.selected" ng-click="test(service)" btn-checkbox >{{service.name}}</label>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="service in availability.services"><span ng-show="service.selected">{{service.id}}</span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does this add exactly?